# simplest syntax for passing in an array of subclasses of a polymorphic base class into a constructor

Tags: c++, vector, list-initialization

Here's working code, that I'd like to simplify the calling of.  Let's start with the call:

```
Config c2( {
           new ConfigPairInt(  "one",   1   ),
           new ConfigPairDouble( "two",   2.0 ),
           new ConfigPairString( "three", "3" )
} );
```

The first thing I'd like to get rid of is the `new`'s.  (If I do `new` like this I suppose it's a memory leak?)  However when I make `Config`'s constructor take `vector<ConfigPair&>` and remove these `new`'s I get pages of errors that don't make sense to me.

Second thing I'd like to get rid of is the type class names.  If I instead switch to curly-brace initializers, then the compiler *does* know that the braced-initializer list is `ConfigPair*` and so everything it sees should be an initializer for `ConfigPair` *or one of its subclasses.*  But does the compiler actually search subclass constructors?  Apparently not.  *(I do have an idea which is to make ConfigPair do the job of all its subclasses, and give it three different constructors.  It'd no longer be polymorphic.   And not being polymorphic, I could then also get rid of the `new` because the vector could be of this `ConfigPair` class instead of `ConfigPair*` which is needed because of the polymorphism.  However the polymorphism seems to fit the problem perfectly so I'm loathe to abandon it.)*

Third thing I'd like to get rid of is the braces around the `vector` initializer.  I think I could do this with a parameter pack but I can't get the resulting list of subclass parameters to initialize the vector.

```
class ConfigPair {
public:
  ConfigPair( const char* pszName_in ) :
    pszName( newstring( pszName_in ) )
  {
  };

  virtual ~ConfigPair() {
    free( (char*) pszName );
  };

  const char* pszName;
};



class Config {
public:
 
  Config( std::vector<ConfigPair*> apcpair )
  {
      for( ConfigPair* pcpair: apcpair )
          // do something
  }
};



class ConfigPairInt : public ConfigPair {
public:
  ConfigPairInt( const char* pszName_in, int iValue_in ) :
    ConfigPair( pszName_in ),
    iValue( iValue_in )
  {
  };

  int         iValue;
};



class ConfigPairDouble : public ConfigPair {
public:
  ConfigPairDouble( const char* pszName_in, double dValue_in ) :
    ConfigPair( pszName_in ),
    dValue( dValue_in )
  {
  };
  double      dValue;
};

  

class ConfigPairString : public ConfigPair {
public:
  ConfigPairString( const char* pszName_in, const char* pszValue_in ) :
    ConfigPair( pszName_in ),
    pszValue( newstring( pszValue_in ) )
  {
  };

  virtual ~ConfigPairString() {
    free( (char*) pszValue );
  };

  const char* pszValue;
};
```

Comment: `Config( std::vector<ConfigPair*> apcpair )` seems to be best suited. Your bas class should be abstract, or a completely abstract interface, to allow calling `virtual` functions with it. Also consider to make the parameter `const` as long you don't want to change anything there.

Comment: Another thing is that you don't necessarily need to create a new derived class for each possible pair of different types, you may consider to use a `std::variant` or `std::any` to overcome this problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ would you be able to give a longer example of this?

Comment: Regarding the memory leaks, consider to use a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), instead of the raw pointers. These will manage the memory automatically.

Comment: _"would you be able to give a longer example of this?"_ Well, yes. But you should probably get a bit more specific with your requirements in the question. I could start with a raw draft.

Comment: OK, I believe that's it for a 1st shot. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS Remy and Panta point out in other answers: *You simply can't get rid of the derived type names if you want to use polymorphism, since the compiler needs to know which types to create.*  Since this is the most typing for the caller, to eliminate it is a priority.  Thus polymorphism is ruled out.

Instead, what was a virtual base class for different kinds of pairs now becomes a "Swiss Army Knife" able to do the job of what were its subclasses.  It has various constructors, and the added overhead of an enum to know which constructor was called.

```
public:
  ConfigPair( const char* pszName_in, int iValue_in ) {
    cfgpair.type    = TypeInt64;
    cfgpair.pszName = newstring( pszName_in );
    cfgpair.u.i     = iValue_in;
  }

  ConfigPair( const char* pszName_in, double dValue_in ) {
    cfgpair.type    = TypeDouble;
    cfgpair.pszName = newstring( pszName_in );
    cfgpair.u.d     = dValue_in;
  }

  ConfigPair( const char* pszName_in, const char* pszValue_in ) {
    cfgpair.type     = TypeSz;
    cfgpair.pszName  = newstring( pszName_in );
    cfgpair.pszValue = newstring( pszValue_in );
  }
```

Given that `ConfigPair` is now the only class being passed into the `Config` constructor means that compiler's awareness of that constructor's type requirement allows it to deduce the object type when called.  Thus, the class name is dispensed with.

Further, since the array contents are now homogenous, we can put the `ConfigPair`'s themselves into an array, instead of (as was initially necessary) only storing *pointers* to the `ConfigPair` subclass objects.  Thus, the new (or the alternative and non-memory-leaking but even more verbose `shared_pointer<ConfigPairXXX>()` notation).

```
  Config( const char* pszName_in, // name only used for debugging messages
          std::vector<ConfigPair> acpair ) :
      Config( pszName_in )
  {
      for ( const ConfigPair cpair: acpair )
          cpair.Set( this );
  }
```

And for the caller:

```
Config c2( { { "one",   1   },
             { "two",   2.0 },
             { "three", "3" } } );
```

Finally, that leaves the outer curly brackets for the braced-initializer-list.  I explored replacing the vector with a parameter pack but then I can't figure out how to make the compiler aware of the type any more, so the type again would be required.  To proceed with this would be one step forward ten steps back in terms of simplicity for the caller, so I am sticking with the braced-initializer-list after all.  *(If there's another alternative to get rid of these outer braces while not needing class names, please let me know.)*

Answer (score 1):

Here's a raw draft of what I would do in your case (as far as described), explanations in comments:

```
using ValueType = std::variant<std::string,int,double>; // To get rid of lengthy
                                                        // type names, and 
                                                        // have them
                                                        // change- and  maintainable 
                                                        // at a single point in your 
                                                        // source code
class ConfigPair {
public:
  ConfigPair( const std::string& name_in, ValueType value ) : 
                              // ^^^^^^^ Ditch "Hungarian notation" for heaven's sake!
    name( name_in ) {}

  virtual ~ConfigPair() {}; // Destructor doesn't need to do anything
                            // std::string manages memory already

  std::string name; // Is compatible with const char* for initialization
  ValueType  value;
};

using PConfigPair = std::shared_ptr<ConfigPair>;
// or in case that Config should take full ownership of ConfigPair's
// using PConfigPair = std::shared_ptr<ConfigPair>;
```

---

```
class Config {
public:
  Config( std::vector<PConfigPair> apcpair )
  {
      for( PConfigPair pcpair: apcpair )
          // do something
  }
// Maybe store the vector here as class member, if Config should take full
// ownership of those ConfigPair's
// std::vector<PConfigPair> config_pairs;
//
// In any case you don't need to care about manual memory management
};
```

---

```
Config c2( { std::make_shared<ConfigPair>("one",1), // std::make_unique alternatively
             std::make_shared<ConfigPair>("two",2.0),
             std::make_shared<ConfigPair>("three","3") } );
```

---

Docs:

- [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)
- [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)  (alternatively you can use `std::unique_ptr`, depending on ownership semantics)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I haven't used or even seen `variant` before.  I must study this, In addition to the three `ConfigPair` I mentioned I will also need a few more, including a heirarchical one whereby the second argument is itself a vector of `ConfigPair` subclasses.  Do you see how to add that to variant?

Comment: Would `name( name_in )` be more efficient as `name( std::move( name_in ) )`?

Comment: Rather than `variant`, I suppose I could make `ConfigPair` a template and let the user give any type supporting assign, etc., as an argument.

Comment: I see: `make_shared` will make the object on the heap, but once the constructor returns, there will be no more references to the objects and they can be freed.  Until now I've only looked at large-scale design with `make_shared`, and haven't seen such a small, tactical use.  I like this 10/10 from the technical standpoint, but it seems like a big step backwards for the true goal, which is making the object easier for the *caller* to use.

Comment: @SwissFrank As mentioned alternatively you can use `std::unique_ptr`. Moving doesn't gain anything vs the `const` reference parameter. A template would be an alternative, but `Config` class needs to know about the concrete types again.

Comment: I used to live in Zurich: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%C3%BCrichsee-Schifffahrtsgesellschaft#/media/File:Panta_Rhei_-_Rapperswil_Lindenhof_2011-06-19_15-14-06.JPG

Comment: @SwissFrank Oh, that's nice :-)

Comment: @SwissFrank Regarding ease of use for the caller, you can write a little wrapper frunction called `make_config_pair()` or such, which hides the `std::make_shared` / `std::make_unique` for the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the use of `new` and `vector` easily enough, by using a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for the `Config` constructor, eg:

```cpp
class Config
{
public:
    template<typename... Ts>
    Config(const Ts&... args)
    {
        const ConfigPair* arr[] = {&args...};
        // use arr as needed...
        for( const ConfigPair *arg: arr ) {
            // do something with arg...
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Config c2(
        ConfigPairInt("one", 1),
        ConfigPairDouble("two", 2.0),
        ConfigPairString("three", "3")
    );
    // use c2 as needed...
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/dPgOap)

You simply can't get rid of the derived type names if you want to use polymorphism, since the compiler needs to know which types to create.  Using a brace-initializer by itself doesn't tell the compiler WHICH type to make:

```
Config c2(
    {"one", 1},    // error: WHICH type?
    {"two", 2.0},  // error: WHICH type?
    {"three", "3"} // error: WHICH type?
);
```

If you want this kind of syntax, then get rid of the polymorphism altogether, just have `ConfigPair` itself handle any value type, via `std::variant`, `std::any`, or equivalent.

Comment: *You simply can't get rid of the derived type names if you want to use polymorphism, since the compiler needs to know which types to create. Using a brace-initializer by itself doesn't tell the compiler WHICH type to make:*  Well, there's only one constructor in scope for `ConfigPair` *or its subclasses* that matches that signature.  It's definitely something a *human* could do, and I *think* it's something the spec *could require* the compiler to do.  But if you say the spec doesn't say the compiler should do it, then agreed and understood.

Comment: If the `Config` constructor takes `ConfiPair*` or `ConfigPair&` as input, the compiler will not automatically go hunting for and call matching derived constructors for you, you have to call them explicitly yourself.

Comment: *the compiler will not automatically go hunting for and call matching derived constructors for you*  sigh, maybe in C++23?  I think it'd be technically possible in that there's only one matching subclass constructor in scope and it could be found extremely quickly...

Comment: Maybe in *this specific example*, but not *in general*, no. What do you think it will do if it finds multiple matching constructors for a given parameter list? How do you expect it to choose which type to construct?  So, no, just, no.

Comment: *Maybe in this specific example, but not in general, no. What do you think it will do if it finds multiple matching constructors for a given parameter list? *  The same thing it does whenever it finds multiple possible matches: produce an error that there are multiple possible matches.

Comment: OK, thanks Remy!  I've tried the variadic template ("parameter pack") and as you say, it requires the caller supply the class name even if the class is no longer polymorphic.  If I eliminate polymorphism and have the base class handle 3 different constructors, can you see a way to avoid writing the outer {} in `Config c( { {"one", 1},{"two",2.0},{"three","3"}} );` ?